# Apache Spark Transformations: groupByKey vs reduceByKey vs aggregateByKey

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

These three Apache Spark Transformations are little confusing.  Is there any way I can determine when to use which one and when to avoid one?

Comment: note there is also `combineByKey`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [official guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) explains it well enough.

I will highlight differences (you have RDD of type `(K, V)`):

1. if you **need** to keep the values, then use `groupByKey`
2. if you **no need** to keep the values, but you need to get some aggregated info about each group (items of the original RDD, which have the same `K`), you have two choices: `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey` (`reduceByKey` is kind of particular `aggregateByKey`)

   - 2.1 if you **can** provide an operation which take as an input `(V, V)` and returns `V`, so that all the values of the group can be reduced to the one single value of the *same* type, then use `reduceByKey`. As a result you will have RDD of the same `(K, V)` type.
   - 2.2 if you **can not** provide this aggregation operation, then use `aggregateByKey`. It happens when you reduce values to *another* type. So you will have `(K, V2)` as a result.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Hlib answer, I would like to add few more points.

- `groupByKey()` is just to group your dataset based on a key.
- `reduceByKey()` is something like ***grouping + aggregation***. We can say reduceBykey() equvelent to `dataset.group(...).reduce(...)`.
- `aggregateByKey()` is logically same as reduceByKey() but it lets you return result in different type. In another words, it lets you have a input as **type x** and aggregate result as **type y**.  For example (1,2),(1,4) as input and (1,"six") as output.