# Spark Dataset: Reduce, Agg, Group or GroupByKey for a Dataset<Tuple2> Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset `<Tuple2<String, Double>>` as follows:

```
<A,1>
<B,2>
<C,2>
<A,2>
<B,3>
<B,4>
```

And need to reduce it by the String to sum the values using Spark Java API so that the final result should look like below:

```
<A,3>
<B,9>
<C,2>
```

Shall I use Reduce, Agg, Group or GroupByKey? and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Spark Transformations: groupByKey vs reduceByKey vs aggregateByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806638/apache-spark-transformations-groupbykey-vs-reducebykey-vs-aggregatebykey)

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking about Dataset, not RDD.

Comment: Yup, but Dataset has only groupBy or groupByKey and reduceGroup or agg. No reduceByKey, that's why I suggested duplicate. Yup, it's not, but also your question should be corrected

Comment: Actually in Java, Dataset has  Reduce, Agg, Group and GroupByKey. Just updated my question.

Comment: But not reduceByKey :P That caused my mistake. Nevermind, I rolled back my close vote, sorry :)

Comment: No worries.. Any idea to how to solve the question?

Comment: TL;DR Use groupBy+agg as it will be the fastest way. More complex answer I can post tomorrow ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152399/discussion-between-fattah-safa-and-t-gaweda).

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have Dataset

```
Dataset<Tuple2<String, Double>> ds = ..;
```

Then you can  call `groupBy` function and `sum` like below

```
ds.groupBy(col("_1")).sum("_2").show();
```

Or you can convert it to `Dataset<Row>` and call `groupBy` function

```
Dataset<Row> ds1 = ds.toDF("key","value");
ds1.groupBy(col("key")).sum("value").show();
```